# Asp.net How to set position for link buttons on a map

Tags: css, asp.net

I am creating a search page based on continents. And I need to let the user click(choose) a continent and based on this choice. I do backend logic.

What I tried is to set a world map as a background of a div. And on this map I put the linkbuttons that represent the continent (as attached).

The problem is when I resize the screen the linkbuttons go into wrong positions. So please help me to find a way to PIN the buttons (continent names) to the map when resize or open the page on different screens.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for trying to help. I just solved the problem and likeed to share the solution.

I have solved this using map on the image. So I made the continents clickable on the image without putting any controls on the image.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a link to a youtube video that shows you how to use google maps API. This may make what you are doing a little easier. I recently used this to create a mobile tour app.

[Google Maps API](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zxf1mnP5zcw&list=PL_eapZEKJ2nj9kXSHr4tXKH9IwdTudKsW&index=4&t=0s)

Comment: I need to put continents on an image and do backend code when this continent clicked. I think this is no need for location services using googles maps..